# Prove $\left(\dbinom nk \right)= \left(\dbinom{k+1}{n-1}\right)$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, multisets

I need to prove $\left(\!\dbinom nk \!\right)= \left(\!\dbinom{k+1}{n-1}\!\right)$ where the double parens denote **[multiset coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets)** and $n,k$ are integers with $1 ≤ k≤ n$ using an algebraic proof.

I have already tried, but it doesn't work out.

Comment: No, they are not equal.

Comment: Would you be referring to [this identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients)?

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: No, i talking about multiset https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: Nobody can tell by what you typed up there, so you'll need to spell it out for what. Just say $n \textrm{ choose } k$ for a binomial coefficient and $n \textrm{ choose } i,j,k$ for a multinomial coefficient and then someone can fix it in latex.

Comment: It's the last question https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnx0aGVsbW9kZWFyYXVqb3xneDpjNzA3MTM0NDc4MDk3YjU

Comment: Can you explain what $(\binom{n}{k})$ is? I'm unfamiliar with that notation.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate cause I answered it some time ago after some longer research how to nicely TeX those things

Answer (score 4):

$$\left( \dbinom nk \right)
=\binom{n+k-1}k
=\binom{n+k-1}{(n+k-1)-k}
=\binom{(k+1)+(n-1)-1}{n-1}
= \left(\dbinom{k+1}{n-1}\right)$$